# Do I need to do anything to clean up $watch-es when they're $destroy'd?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to avoid memory leaks, so I'm wondering if `$watch`es are automatically removed when a scope is `$destroy`'d, or what should I do to clean up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [$destroy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) docs says it:

> Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer propagate to the current scope and its children.

This means that your $watches are not going to be run anymore, once your scope is $destroyed, because they can only be processed by the $digest cycle, which is cancelled when the scope is $destroyed.